# Looking at this graph would you say there is no correlation between these two variables?

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to figure out if there is a correlation between Military Enlistment and the number of U.S. War Films Released between 1980-2021?

This is a graph I made in Tableau for data for the Department of Defense Total Enlistment between 1980-2021 and number of U.S. war films released. Looking at this graph I don't think there was a correlation between the two but wanted to double check. Is there no correlation or is there a negative correlation?

[image]

Comment: There's a clear negative correlation--the two plots trend in opposite directions--but you can't learn anything from it.  It's just one more example of a potential [spurious correlation](https://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations).

Comment: Is it possible that you are wanting to use a correlation as a surrogate for a more interesting question? It is unlikely that one is a cause of the other, but there could well be some shared influences that contribute to a weak (negative) correlation. Exploring those possibilities might be more interesting than testing for a statistical correlation.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the insights.